# Textures distort if I rotate geometry nodes object

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

[image: The wall on the left is fine, but the wall on the right the background texture appears distorted.]

So I made a wall with egyptian symbols tiled using geometry nodes. The background texture of the rock has the texture coordinates of an empty I assiged to it. If I duplicate the geometry nodes wall and rotate it, the background rock textures get distorted. Is there a way to fix this without having to duplicate all of the symbols and assign a new object to use for texture coordinates?

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R5cr2nL7-t4D7iHwGgwxkiTnIeitUyQa/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Of course the textures get distorted when you rotate them, since they are mapped in relation to the empty you've assigned in the _Texture Coordinate_ node. If you only rotate one of the objects, either the wall or the empty, the textures get distorted. Why did you use the empty at all in the first place? Do you need it for adjusting the texture later?

Comment: Since the wall is made up of many individual plane objects, each plane object a symbol on the wall, I used the empty so the background wall texture bound to the coordinates of the empty so the individual planes share a common background texture (rock). I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it! I let the empty handle the vector mapping and the normals the rotation of the faces. Then I added a rotation transform node (Or something close to it. I can't remember the name correctly) between the texture mapping - normals to the mapping node and played with the rotations there until I got it right.

Comment: If your question was solved, please be so kind and mark your answer as "Accepted Answer". This will make it easier for others to see which way leads to the solution, and the question will no longer appear as unsolved: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you!